# Invoke looping / crashing

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, invoke

I want to write Text to a textbox. To be able to do that from different threads, I'm calling a static method that calls an unstatic method that holds the invoke and textbox-writing. When doing this. I'm getting the error, that it can't invoke until the windows handle is set, so I'm setting it. My problem is, that the position of

```
if (!this.IsHandleCreated)
    this.CreateHandle();
```

below in the code is the only one, where my program doesn't crash, but now it's looping (indefinetly) only the BeginInvoke code but not actually the text-setting code below. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
private void ActualLog(string input)
        {
            var currentForm = form as Main;

            if (!this.IsHandleCreated)
                this.CreateHandle();
            if (currentForm.txtServerLog.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(ActualLog), new object[] { input });
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                currentForm.txtServerLog.Text += input + "\r\n";
                currentForm.txtServerLog.Refresh();
            }
        }

        public static void Log(string input)
        {
            Main main = new Main();
            main.ActualLog(input);
        }
```

From my thread, I would call `Log("Any String");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your infinite loop is because, whenever txtServerLog has InvokeRequired as true, you're invoking an Action that sents ActualLog as an action. Essentially, every time you get on that conditional path, you're starting back again from ActualLog. Imagine if you took out all the other code in the method and just had:

```
 private void ActualLog(string input)
 {
      ActualLog(input);
 }
```

I might be missing some wrinkle here, but I'm pretty sure that's exactly what you're doing here. Given that in the case where txtServerLog requires you to invoke commands you don't ever do anything to change that state, you're just going to loop forever.

What you'd want to do is separate the function you're actually trying to invoke into a separate log - I'm assuming that your goal is to update the TextBox.

So, an example:

```
private void UpdateTextBox(string input)
{
    currentForm.txtServerLog.Text += input + "\r\n";
    currentForm.txtServerLog.Refresh();
}
```

and your ActualLog function:

```
private void ActualLog(string input)
{
    var currentForm = form as Main;

    if (!this.IsHandleCreated)
    {
        this.CreateHandle();
    }
    if (currentForm.txtServerLog.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<string>(UpdateTextBox), new object[] { input }); //Make sure to use Invoke, not BeginInvoke
        return;
    }

    UpdateTextBox(input);
}
```

Keep in mind that if you return on an if-condition and don't have an else-if, there's no functional reason to have an else branch - you can just include them after the if block.

A point about the code you're passing - you don't actually call Log() within it, so I'm not really sure why it's there or whether it's relevant to your issues.

Comment: @JanH. I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but I've included a sample above.

Comment: Thank you! When using Invoke instead of BeginInvoke in your example it works. The thing with the two functions was just so I could call Log() from annother Thread, since Invoke is not allowed in a static function (so I just put it in a unstatic one and call it from a static one). But thanks anyways :)

Comment: @JanH. Ah, I spend more time on WPF than WinForms, so I'm a little rusty on the Invoke/BeginInvoke distinction. Glad to hear it helped!